# python 2.7 using financial times education api to generate plain text articles

Tags: python-2.7

at the bottom of:

https://developer.pearson.com/apis/ft-education-api/#!/ftarticles/listArticles_get_0

i am trying to get a list of articles using the set parameters.

i have registered for, and received an API key.

the issue is that i am unable to generate a list of articles, say on '2014-05-01'

note: financial times set up the API to allow students to get plain text articles 30 days after the original article was published.

done extremely small amount of research and understand i may need to use python to receive the actual content...have python installed (familiar with absolute basics)...trying to get nothing more than plain text documents of articles.

thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code that is failing and explain exactly what goes wrong.

Comment: ^thanks. don't want to waste anyone's time, and if the question is too vague i understand. i haven't written any code in python to use the api. absolutely not looking for anyone to explain what code might word, rather, my primary question is: does an API (in general) require the user to write a program in order to receive the content? with respect to this post, is it incorrect to believe that the interface at the bottom of the link (originally posted) is capable of providing a PDF type document that the end user can then download? thanks.